# Set BSTR to null

Tags: c++, vb6, bstr

In a Visual C++ i have a function like shown below.it is a dll code. From vb6 application i am calling dll and run the function and get result.But every time when i call this from my vb6 application(without closing vb6 exe) i get result with appended values of last result if exe is not closed.(ex when i run first result is "a" for second time it is "aa" and so on).So i am using i think it is due to BSTR Message not being set to NULL in the beginning of this function.
Below is code in VC++ . So how to set BSTR to null or empty in the beginning or how to solve my error?

```
BSTR __stdcall getHardDriveComputerID (short* disk_cnt , short* method)
                                                   
{

BSTR Message=NULL;

int i,length;
size_t len = 0;

int done = FALSE;

__int64 id = 0;
OSVERSIONINFO version;

strcpy (HardDriveSerialNumber, "");

memset (&version, 0, sizeof (version));
version.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof (OSVERSIONINFO);
GetVersionEx (&version);
if (version.dwPlatformId == VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT)
{
      //  this works under WinNT4 or Win2K if you have admin rights
#ifdef PRINTING_TO_CONSOLE_ALLOWED
   
    printf ("\nTrying to read the drive IDs using physical access with admin rights\n");
#endif
    done = ReadPhysicalDriveInNTWithAdminRights ();
    *disk_cnt=hard_disk_cnt;

    *method=1;

    if ( ! done) 
    {
        done = ReadIdeDriveAsScsiDriveInNT ();
        *disk_cnt=hard_disk_cnt;
    
        *method=2;

    }

    
    if ( ! done)
    {done = ReadPhysicalDriveInNTWithZeroRights ();
        *disk_cnt=hard_disk_cnt;
        *method=3;
        
    if ( ! done)
    { done = ReadPhysicalDriveInNTUsingSmart ();
        *disk_cnt=hard_disk_cnt;
        *method=4;
    
    }
}
else
{
     //  this works under Win9X and calls a VXD
  int attempt = 0;

     //  try this up to 10 times to get a hard drive serial number
  for (attempt = 0;
       attempt < 10 && ! done && 0 == HardDriveSerialNumber [0];
       attempt++)
     done = ReadDrivePortsInWin9X ();
       *disk_cnt=hard_disk_cnt;
        *method=5;
       
}

if (HardDriveSerialNumber [0] > 0)
{
  char *p = HardDriveSerialNumber;

  WriteConstantString ("HardDriveSerialNumber", HardDriveSerialNumber);

     //  ignore first 5 characters from western digital hard drives if
     //  the first four characters are WD-W
  if ( ! strncmp (HardDriveSerialNumber, "WD-W", 4)) 
     p += 5;
  for ( ; p && *p; p++)
  {
     if ('-' == *p) 
        continue;
     id *= 10;
     switch (*p)
     {
        case '0': id += 0; break;
        case '1': id += 1; break;
        case '2': id += 2; break;
        case '3': id += 3; break;
        case '4': id += 4; break;
        case '5': id += 5; break;
        case '6': id += 6; break;
        case '7': id += 7; break;
        case '8': id += 8; break;
        case '9': id += 9; break;
        case 'a': case 'A': id += 10; break;
        case 'b': case 'B': id += 11; break;
        case 'c': case 'C': id += 12; break;
        case 'd': case 'D': id += 13; break;
        case 'e': case 'E': id += 14; break;
        case 'f': case 'F': id += 15; break;
        case 'g': case 'G': id += 16; break;
        case 'h': case 'H': id += 17; break;
        case 'i': case 'I': id += 18; break;
        case 'j': case 'J': id += 19; break;
        case 'k': case 'K': id += 20; break;
        case 'l': case 'L': id += 21; break;
        case 'm': case 'M': id += 22; break;
        case 'n': case 'N': id += 23; break;
        case 'o': case 'O': id += 24; break;
        case 'p': case 'P': id += 25; break;
        case 'q': case 'Q': id += 26; break;
        case 'r': case 'R': id += 27; break;
        case 's': case 'S': id += 28; break;
        case 't': case 'T': id += 29; break;
        case 'u': case 'U': id += 30; break;
        case 'v': case 'V': id += 31; break;
        case 'w': case 'W': id += 32; break;
        case 'x': case 'X': id += 33; break;
        case 'y': case 'Y': id += 34; break;
        case 'z': case 'Z': id += 35; break;
     }                            
  }
}

id %= 100000000;
if (strstr (HardDriveModelNumber, "IBM-"))
   id += 300000000;
else if (strstr (HardDriveModelNumber, "MAXTOR") ||
        strstr (HardDriveModelNumber, "Maxtor"))
  id += 400000000;
else if (strstr (HardDriveModelNumber, "WDC "))
  id += 500000000;
else
  id += 600000000;

 #ifdef PRINTING_TO_CONSOLE_ALLOWED

printf ("\nHard Drive Serial Number__________: %s\n", 
       HardDriveSerialNumber);
printf ("\nHard Drive Model Number___________: %s\n", 
       HardDriveModelNumber);
printf ("\nComputer ID_______________________: %I64d\n", id);

#endif




char tempdisk_serials[]="";
for(i = 0 ; i<=hard_disk_cnt ; i++)
  {
  if(hard_disk_serial[i] != "")
  {
  strcat(tempdisk_serials, hard_disk_serial[i]);
  length = strlen(tempdisk_serials);



  /* Check if we need to insert newline */
  if(tempdisk_serials[length-1] != '\n')
  {
    tempdisk_serials[length] = '\n';             /* Append a newline       */
    tempdisk_serials[length+1] = '\0';           /* followed by terminator */
  }
 }
}



//Converting char[] to BSTR
Message = SysAllocStringByteLen (tempdisk_serials, strlen(tempdisk_serials));



return (BSTR) Message;

}
```

This is modified code of shown in link http://www.winsim.com/diskid32/diskid32.cpp

**EDIT**

Its not problem with tempdisk_serials actually .This variable is set from hard_disk_serial. It is declared globally as char hard_disk_serial[16][1024];(not shown in code in my question) . How to clear this variable in my function? i tried hard_disk_serial[][]={0}; and it gives syntax error.

Comment: Casting a `BSTR` to a `BSTR` does nothing.

Comment: Setting Message = NULL in the beginning would do nothing.  You need to post the entire code for us to see the problem.

Comment: tempdisk variable is not cleaned, probably.

Comment: `char tempdisk_serials[]=""; strcat(tempdisk_serials, ...);` This is a buffer overrun. `tempdisk_serials` is one character in size, only capable of holding a terminating NUL and nothing else. Your `strcat` writes to some random area in memory. Purely by accident, this area is not overwritten between calls, and you keep adding to it. Bottom line, undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik So what i need to change? Please help

Comment: You need to allocate sufficient size in that buffer.  The code example doesn't show where hard_disk_serial is declared or used, so it is hard to know the length.  Using a class like std::string instead of C-style strings would make it easier.

Comment: @MobyDisk I am not getting error like buffer overflow.(it is char hard_disk_serial[16][1024];) I Think u didnt get my error . when i call this procedure i should get answer hard disk sl no of the pc . Now when i call it again and again(without closing vb6 app) i get serial no appended to its serial no. So its like that variable or message is not being reset.

Comment: @nikitoz Ok. How to clear tempdisk variable?

Comment: @nikitoz Its not problem with tempdisk_serials actually .this variable is set from hard_disk_serial. it is declared globally as char hard_disk_serial[16][1024];(not shown in code in my question) . How to clear this variable in my function? i tried hard_disk_serial[][]={0};  and it gives syntax error. please help

Comment: I see how nikitoz's solution solves your problem.  But the bug that @IgorTandetnik pointed out is still a problem.  The code is overflowing tempdisk_serials even if it isn't causing a crash today, it might do so someday in the future.  That really should be fixed as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear buffer, use memset function [doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/)

```
memset (hard_disk_serial, 0, 1024*16);
```